# Getting same hashcode every time before serialization and after seriadeserialization of object without using readResolve method in Java why?

Tags: java, serialization, singleton

Getting same `Hashcode` every time before `serialization` and after `deserialization` of object without using `readResolve()` method in Java  why ?
Here is my class

```
public class SerializedSingletonClass implements Serializable{
            
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 18989987986l;
            
    private SerializedSingletonClass(){};
            
    private static class InstanceHelper {
        private static SerializedSingletonClass obj = new   SerializedSingletonClass();
    }
            
    public static SerializedSingletonClass getInstance(){
        return InstanceHelper.obj;
    }
}
```

Test Class   --

```
public class TestSingleton {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // Test Serialization for singleton pattern
            SerializedSingletonClass instanse1 = SerializedSingletonClass
                    .getInstance();
            ObjectOutputStream obs = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                    "filename1.ser"));
            obs.writeObject(instanse1);
            obs.close();
            ObjectInputStream objInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream("filename1.ser"));
            SerializedSingletonClass instance2 = (SerializedSingletonClass) objInputStream
                    .readObject();
            objInputStream.close();
            System.out.println("instance1==" + instanse1.getClass().hashCode());
            System.out.println("instance2==" + instance2.getClass().hashCode());
}
```

}

> **Output ::**
>
> instance1==1175576547
>
> instance2==1175576547

Comment: Share the entire code specially how you serialize and deserialize

Comment: I don't see anything in that snippet that produces the output you mention. How are you computing hash codes, and how are you serializing and deserializing the objects? And also if you've properly implemented your hashing function to hash based on actual values of the object, wouldn't you *expect* it to stay the same after the object is deserialized? To me that seems like a successful [de]serialization.

Comment: This is my test class that I forgot to paste ::

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your objects are instances of the same class, SerializedSingletonClass. You're getting the hashCode from the class, not from the instance. `instanse1.getClass()` evaluates to the same thing as `instance2.getClass()`, so of course they produce the same hashCode.

To find the hashCode of the objects, use `instanse1.hashCode()` and `instance2.hashCode()`.

Comment: thanks identified the issue , I was unaware that class also has hashcode and that is different from object.